# Printing the second half of a linked list in reverse order

Tags: c++, linked-list

I want to print the elements of a linked list, first in their order and then, once I reach the middle, in reverse order (from the last one backwards). For example:

If the elements are: `1 2 3 4 5 6`
It should print: `1 2 3 6 5 4`
But it's printing: `1 2 3 5 4`

Why isn't it printing the last element? How can this be solved?

```
void reverse()
{
    int c=1;
    node *current,*prev,*temp;
    current=head;
    prev=NULL;
    std::stack<int>s;
    while(current->next!=NULL)
    {
        c++;
        s.push(current->data);
        current=current->next;
    }

    int mid=0;
    if((c%2)==0)
    {
        mid=c/2;
    }
    else
    {
        mid=(c+1)/2;
    }
    current=head;
    for(int i=0;i<mid;i++)
    {
        cout<<current->data<<"\t";
        current=current->next;
    }

    for(int i=mid;i>1;i--)
    {
       std::cout<<s.top()<<"\t";
       s.pop();
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Off topic: `cout<<current->data<<"\t";` suggests using namespace std; is in play. Take care that you don't accidentally wind up calling `std::reverse`.

Comment: On topic: looks like a problem that can be easily identified by stepping through the function with debugging software. A debugger almost certainly shipped with your development environment and it's in your best interests to learn how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code here:
http://ideone.com/bbzsSy

2 issues:

- `while(current->next!=NULL)` should be: `while(current!=NULL)`
  This way you be sure that you can dereferencing the pointer, plus you also push the last node.
- `for(int i=0;i<mid;i++)` should be: `for(int i=0;i<lastFordward;i++)`
  Where `lastFordward=(c%2)?mid-1:mid;`
  This way avoid to print the mid position twice when `c` is even.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that the list contains only one element. In this case this loop

```
while(current->next!=NULL)
{
    c++;
    s.push(current->data);
    current=current->next;
}
```

will be executed never and as result the stack will be empty. Moreover the function initially has undefined behavior when the list in turn is empty and hence `head` is equal to NULL and you may not access `current->next` data member.

Well now let's assume that the list contains exactly two elements. The loop will be executed only once and the variable `c` gets value 2.  The calculated value of the variable `mid` will be equal to 1.

So this loop

```
for(int i=0;i<mid;i++)
{
    cout<<current->data<<"\t";
    current=current->next;
}
```

executes only one iteration and the first element is outputted.

However the next loop

```
  for(int i=mid;i>1;i--)
  {
     std::cout<<s.top()<<"\t";
     s.pop();


  }
```

will; be executed never because its condition `i > 1` yields `false` because mid is equal to 1.

So the program has two wrong loops that should be rewritten.

Below is a demonstrative program that shows how the function can be implemented.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
} *head = nullptr;

void append( int data )
{
    node **current = &head;

    while ( *current ) current = &( *current )->next;

    *current = new node { data, nullptr };
}

void clear()
{
    while ( head )
    {
        node *tmp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete tmp;
    }
}

void reverse()
{
    std::stack<int> s;

    for ( node *current = head; current; current = current->next )
    {
        s.push( current->data );
    }

    std::stack<int>::size_type middle = ( s.size() + 1 ) / 2;
    std::stack<int>::size_type i = 0;

    for ( node *current = head; i < middle; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << current->data << '\t';
        current = current->next;
    }

    for ( i = s.size() - i; i != 0; i-- )
    {
        std::cout << s.top() << '\t';
        s.pop();
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() 
{
    const int N = 10;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j <= i; j++ ) append( j );
        reverse();
        clear();
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0   

0   1   

0   1   2   

0   1   3   2   

0   1   2   4   3   

0   1   2   5   4   3   

0   1   2   3   6   5   4   

0   1   2   3   7   6   5   4   

0   1   2   3   4   8   7   6   5   

0   1   2   3   4   9   8   7   6   5
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `while` loop you are checking if `current->next` is `null` you need to check if `current` is `null`.

```
while(current)
{
    c++;
    s.push(current->data);
    current=current->next;
}
```

You weren't adding the last number into the `stack`

Answer (score 0):

This method can work ... declare a function to get the size of the linkList

```
public int size()
{
    int counter = 0;
    node *nodePtr = head;

    while (nodePtr)
    {
        if (nodePtr->next != null)
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }

    return counter;
}
```

then if size returned is an even number ...

```
int c = size()/2;
```

else ...

```
int c = (size()+1)/2;
```

then initialize and array and print them in reverse .... try it out might work :)

Answer (score 0):

In a typical linked list implementation the last node points to nothing (typically nullptr). Your stop condition for adding the existing elements (current->next!=nullptr) to the stack therefore doesn't include the last element.

Iterating over current would be a better approach as that would stop one after the last node.

Also note that this will have an impact on your mid-point calculation as it is off by one from the start.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite going to compile, but this is somewhat fewer lines:

```
// assert myList is sorted before called
// if it's not, add       
// std::sort(myList.begin(), myList.end());
// as the first line of the function
void reverseLatterHalf(std::vector& myList)  {
  auto it = myList.begin() + myList.size() / 2;
  std::reverse(it, myList.end());
}
```